# How to write files without overwriting them with each loop iteration

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, biopython, fasta

The following code is to analyze the amino acid composition of FASTA sequences (.faa files)

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.SeqUtils.ProtParam import ProteinAnalysis
import fastaparser
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

filename = input("Please enter the full path of the amino acid sequence file!: ")
pH_input = input("At which pH should the analysis be conducted? ")
flexibility_ynu = input("Do you wish a flexibility analysis?\n   (1) Yes\n   (0) No\n")

if pH_input == "":
    pH= 7.4
elif pH_input != "":
    pH = pH_input

f = open(filename + "_analysis.txt","w+")
for record in SeqIO.parse(filename, 'fasta'):
    X = ProteinAnalysis(str(record.seq))
    print("ANALYSIS OF", record, "\n ----------- \n -----------", file=f)
    #
    pd_count_amino_acids = pd.DataFrame(X.count_amino_acids(), index=[1])
    print("number of amino acids: \n",pd_count_amino_acids , file=f)
    plt_acc = pd_count_amino_acids.plot.bar()
    plt.savefig(filename + "_count_amino_acids_plot.pdf")
    #
    pd_get_amino_acids_percent = pd.DataFrame(X.get_amino_acids_percent(), index=[1])
    print("\n percentage of amino acids: \n", pd_get_amino_acids_percent, file=f)
    plt_acp = pd_get_amino_acids_percent.plot.bar()
    plt.savefig(filename + "amino_acids_percent_plot.pdf")
    #
    print("\n molecular weight: {:.2f}".format(X.molecular_weight()), file=f)
    print("\n aromaticity: {:.2f}".format(X.aromaticity()), file=f)
    print("\n instability index: {:.2f}".format(X.instability_index()), file=f)
    if flexibility_ynu == "1":
        print("\n flexibility: ", X.flexibility(), file=f)
    print("\n IEP: ", X.isoelectric_point(), file=f)
    print("therefore its charge at pH = ",pH," is {:.2f}".format(X.charge_at_pH(pH)), file=f)
    print("secondary structure fraction: (Helix, Turn, Sheet): ", X.secondary_structure_fraction(), "\n\n\n", file=f)
f.close()
print("done")
```

I now would like bar plots for both the absolute and relative number of amino acids, but create a unique plot for every FASTA ID.

For example, [NC_011544](https://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/genomes/Viruses/hosta_virus_x_uid32693/NC_011544.faa) has 5 IDs, so I'd like to generate 10 unique plots (2 per ID, one for absolute, and one for relative number).

Is there any way to do this?

### `NC_011544.faa`

```
>gi|212671454|ref|YP_002308464.1| replicase [Hosta virus X]
MARLREVFSSFTEPNLKTIVQQETYKLAKAELKTIQTYNPYAQTKDAADLLEDLGINTNPHAVTAHTHAA
AKSIENDLYGITSHYLPKTPITFLFMKRGKLQFFKRGPQHNDLFFYTTHEPKDVIRYQSEDQTADMFRVP
TSTGFIGDTLHFLSLKYLHRLFLKNPNLNTLYATMVLPPEAMYRMASIYPEIYQIQYQEDGFLYIPGGHG
GAAYFHTYDTLTWLRVGQFQAKEFTAHLPKVGDKGANHLFIIQRADLKTPKYRTFVPRRKWVTLPNIFLP
STQANHLFIIQRADLKTPKYRTFVPRRKWVTSNIFLPKHTNARKPILKQTMMQLFLYEKSVKEITFRDVF
AKIRQLIQTKDLEQFDPDELVRLANYVMHTSKLLEKDPYELIEGQGKLQDLVNPIKTWVSEKWQNWFGWK
DYTRLIRALKWVDVDLVLRVMNTRSTPTGIQTSELLPDEAGPPKSKKKRGGKKIPSPEPSRNCRSKSKRT
RGNRAQREKEPHRRKLRWQKENFQRVTVQVHQAPKGDPSPLARFSQSLKELPRRSQPRRLSKFQDFLMSS
TQTRFQIPSSLNRRAGHWRPKQQGTPPTTQEAGTEGPPTTQPGKPTASSPRAAPQPTANAETMEKGSQAS
SATTRGRDPVTDRTREQAPTNLTPEEEALPWKHWLKQLKAVGFKGNETQMDGDGTSISPIEQIKSCPGKP
KSVSKEILETLRSGHAPNFWKPDASRARAYTSDIKNRRTGAAVHMAPQAWKETMDFIAENAERTLHILRH
PWRRRFREEQMSSRDAHKFHFLFDETLVVCPTNELRRDWIDKLPLSEPGSVLTFERALMNPAKGTVIFDD
YTKLPAGFIEAYSICQPNVELVILTGDAKQASHHESNDNAMIAGLDPAAFEFSKFCRYYLNATHRNPRNL
ANALGIYSEKPGNLKVTFTNHLLPEMHILVPSLLKKATLEELGHKCSTYAGCQGVTLSKVQIYLDSNTTL
CSNEVLYTALSRAVEQINFVNSGPFNGPFWAKLEATPYLKTFLRLTREEKINEITPEEPKPKEPEPPKTH
FPVETSAHLYSSITEEMPEKHAREIYNKTHGHTNCVQTDEPLVQMFAHQQAKDEALFWETIEARLRITTS
EANVQELNEKRDIGDLLFHAYHKAMGLPKDPIPFENDLWETCAQEVQQTYLSKPINLIKNGEKRQGPDFD
KNAIMLFLKSQWVKKMEKLGAPTIKPGQTIASFHQITVMLYGTMARYMRRIRDRFCPKHILINCEKTPTQ
ISDFVKAQWDFSDFAYANDFTAFDQSQDGAMLQFEIIKAKFHNIPEDIILGYMDIKTNAKIFLGTLAIMR
LTGEGPTFDANTECNIAYTHLRFNVPENVAQVYAGDDSALSKVCPEKDSFKQFADRLTLKSKPQVFPQTQ
GAWAEFCGLLITPRGIIKDPVKLHASWVLATKLGTLQQIKCVNSYGEDLKLSYDLGDHLQELLSESQCRT
HQVTVRELVKFAGKVEKHQAEIRSVANGNIRQLPFFY
>gi|212671455|ref|YP_002308465.1| 26 kDa protein [Hosta virus X]
MATFASFLSSTRPDFERTNTPLTKPLVIHAVAGAGKTTLLRDFLRANPLTNAQTLGTPDCPTLDGAYIRP
FSGPVANLVNILDEYTAHRHGSWDVLIADPLQHYERAKLPHYICKRSHRLCPATARLLRKLGLDIHSYRE
DESEISFSDIFSGQLEGTVLPLTPLCKDLLERHSCPFKCPSEFIGEQDDIITVVSEIPLSKHPDKTALYR
ALTRHTRRLNVLAPPPYPTP
>gi|212671456|ref|YP_002308466.1| 13 kDa protein [Hosta virus X]
MSSPHRLTPPPNYTPVLLAVVIGVGLAVVTNQLTRSTLPHVGDNIHSLPHGGNYKDGTKSVIYRGPAPFQ
RSHSTAPPFNAVLLLTFAIWFLSCRTRRAAIGIHVCHTCSQTREQQ
>gi|212671457|ref|YP_002308467.1| 8 kDa protein [Hosta virus X]
MQSFCSHLRSGSFPVVLGALLLAFTCATLVLRLGNNNSNNCLIYVDGARAFLEGNCAGISAEVVAALRPH
SHAG
>gi|212671458|ref|YP_002308468.1| coat protein [Hosta virus X]
MASDAPTPPAAPSPVTFTAPTQEQLTSLALPIISTRLPSPDVLNQISVKWQELGVPTASISSTAIALCMA
CYHSGSSGSTLIPGLAPGTTVNYTSLAAAVKSLATLREFARYFAPIIWNYAIEHKIPPANWAAMGYKENT
KYAAFDTFDSILNPAALQPTGGLIRQPTEEELLAHQANSALHIFDSLRNDFASTDGRVTRGHITSNVNSL
NYLPAPEGSS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The code was already creating a plot for each record, however, the same file name was being used for everything, so each new plot and `analysis.txt` was overwriting the previous one.
- Extract the `id` from `record`, as `record_id`, and use that to create unique file names with each loop.
- The following code will now generate a `percent_plot.pdf`, `count_plot.pdf`, and an `analysis.txt` for each `id`
- Use `with open`, which will automatically close the file `f`
- [`.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) is used to transpose the dataframe when plotting, which places the amino acid names on the axis, thereby making the plot easier to read.

```py
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.SeqUtils.ProtParam import ProteinAnalysis

# set pandas display option
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

# input selections were removed for testing
filename = 'NC_011544.faa'
flexibility_ynu =  '1'
pH = 7.4

for record in SeqIO.parse(filename, 'fasta'):
    # get each record id to be used for unique file names
    record_id = record.id.split('|')[1]
    print(record)
    # open the file and use the record id as part of the name, so there will be a unique file for each id
    with open(f"{filename}_{record_id}_analysis.txt","w+") as f:

        X = ProteinAnalysis(str(record.seq))
        print("ANALYSIS OF", record, "\n ----------- \n -----------", file=f)
        #
        pd_count_amino_acids = pd.DataFrame(X.count_amino_acids(), index=[1])
        display(pd_count_amino_acids)  # display is for jupyter notebook, otherwise use print
        print("number of amino acids: \n",pd_count_amino_acids , file=f)
        plt_acc = pd_count_amino_acids.T.plot.bar(legend=False, figsize=(7, 5))
        plt.title(f'Number of Amino Acids for {record_id} in {filename}')
        plt.xticks(rotation=0)
        # add the record id as part of the file name
        plt.savefig(f'{filename}_{record_id}_count_amino_acids_plot.pdf')
        plt.show()
        #
        pd_get_amino_acids_percent = pd.DataFrame(X.get_amino_acids_percent(), index=[1])
        display(pd_get_amino_acids_percent.round(2))  # display is for jupyter notebook, otherwise use print
        print("\n percentage of amino acids: \n", pd_get_amino_acids_percent, file=f)
        plt_acp = pd_get_amino_acids_percent.T.plot.bar(legend=False, figsize=(7, 5))
        plt.title(f'Percentage of Amino Acids for {record_id} in {filename}')
        plt.xticks(rotation=0)
        # add the record id as part of the file name
        plt.savefig(f'{filename}_{record_id}_amino_acids_percent_plot.pdf')
        plt.show()
        #
        print("\n molecular weight: {:.2f}".format(X.molecular_weight()), file=f)
        print("\n aromaticity: {:.2f}".format(X.aromaticity()), file=f)
        print("\n instability index: {:.2f}".format(X.instability_index()), file=f)

        if flexibility_ynu == "1":
            print("\n flexibility: ", X.flexibility(), file=f)

        print("\n IEP: ", X.isoelectric_point(), file=f)
        print("therefore its charge at pH = ",pH," is {:.2f}".format(X.charge_at_pH(pH)), file=f)
        print("secondary structure fraction: (Helix, Turn, Sheet): ", X.secondary_structure_fraction(), "\n\n\n", file=f)
        print('\n')
```

### First ID

[image]

### Second ID

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved it myself (https://github.com/pmaen/biopython/blob/main/proteinanalysis_extended.py) but so far yours works better.